# The name 'UName' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

When trying to register to my database I am receiving the "The name 'UName' does not exist in the current context" error.

Register.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Register" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
     <title>Registration Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <p>This is the registration page</p>
    <a href ="Default.aspx">Home</a> | <a href ="#">Register</a>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <p>Enter First Name :</p>
        <p>
            <asp:TextBox ID="UName" runat="server" Width="271px"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>          
        <p>
             <asp:Button ID="registerButton" runat="server" Text="REGISTER" OnClick="registerEventMethod" />
        </p>
     </div>
     </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Register.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd;
    String queryStr;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void registerEventMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        registerUser();

    }

    private void registerUser()
    {
        String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnString"].ToString();

        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();

        queryStr = "";

        queryStr = "INSERT INTO jamieobr_obecarrentals.users (Forename)" +
        "VALUES('" + UName.Text + "')";

        cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);

        cmd.ExecuteReader();

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

why am I getting this error? I have tried several solutions and all failed.

Comment: Do you have a `Register.aspx.designer.cs` file and is `UName` defined in there?

Comment: A MySqlCommand works with MySqlParameter which is what you need to prevent the SQL Injection vulnerability you currently have.

Comment: @DavidG I dont think I have a designer page, or if I do I cannot locate it in the Solution Explorer

Comment: @AlexK. I am aware of that, this project of mine is not even close to being finished haha, just need some help with my current problem.

Comment: Usually the controls on an aspx page are defined in the designer file which exists as a child of the main page, something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kYUh.png)

Comment: Could it be because the aspx page was imported along with the code behind from a different solution? because I have another aspx page which I built from scratch in the same solution and that has a designer file attached too it. @DavidG

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Check the source to see if there's a designer file there. Alternatively, you may be able to recreate the designer file by making a simple change to the aspx. It's autogenerated anyway.

Comment: @DavidG I will create a fresh aspx and try again, ill get back to you with the results

Comment: @DavidG Still no luck, same error still applies the second I write the code but I do now have the designer file

Comment: And is `UName` in the designer file now?

Comment: Yes its there "protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox UName;" @DavidG

Comment: go to Microsfot.NET[.NET version]\Temporary ASP.NET Files. and delete temparary files for your web site.

e.g for .net 4.0

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
if you use CodeFile directive then compiled files goes to Temporary ASP.NET Files

And also delete bin and object folders from your solution and rebuild the web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my own issue, the first initial issue was that I tried copying the .aspx file into a new solution, however this did not copy along the .aspx.designer.cs file therefore causing the problem.

However after trying to re write a fresh version manually which had a designer file with it I forgot to include the .cs file into the namespace of my solution therefore then generating a new problem.

However after including the .cs file into the namespace, hey presto, it worked!